# How to convert character code to what I want?

Tags: ruby

Doing this:

```
s = "hello"
s[0]
```

outputs the character code value `104`.

What do I need to do to convert the `104` such that it outputs '`h`'?

I am using ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of your options include:

- Use `s[0].chr`
- Use `s[0...1]` or `s[0,1]`
- Upgrade to Ruby 1.9 where strings are no longer considered arrays of bytes, and `s[0]` gives you `"h"` as expected.

Comment: I wish I could upvote once for the correct answer and another time for the even more correct answer of upgrading to 1.9.

Comment: how is upgrading to 1.9 an answer? why would I migrate just to get get my character ? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
104.chr
```

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Integer.html#M000289

Answer (score 0):

Simple, tell Ruby you want the character by adding `.chr`:

```
s[0].chr
```