# In Ruby, given a character code, how can I create a string / character?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert character code to what I want?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542705/how-to-convert-character-code-to-what-i-want)

I am positive this has to be a duplicate, but all search results were in other languages or were the reverse (character to code point).

e.g.

```
charCode = 96

string = # ... ?
```

Comment: Is this intended to be a FAQ type question? (since you answered it) Might want to CW it then?

Comment: @jili: 1) No. As always happened, I looked for 10 minutes, posted, then immediately found the solution. 2) Done!

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with:

```
string = charCode.chr
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.chr` method on `Fixnum`.

`96.chr #=> "c"`